# journalctl reports tally 13, deny 5 but pam_tally2 says no failures

Tags: virtualbox, pam

My server is running virtualbox headless with vboxwebsrv.

Every once in a while (and I have no idea why), the user vbox locks and I can't login.

Usually, I can reset with pam_tally2 -u vbox --reset.

Today, I got the usual login denied again, and journalclt shows:

```
Sep 11 08:00:52 servername vboxwebsrv[26367]: pam_tally2(login:auth): user vbox (1001) tally 13, deny 5
```

But this time around pam_tally2 says:

```
# pam_tally2 --user vbox
Login           Failures Latest failure     From
vbox                0
```

I cannot reset it. I tried pam_tally instead, but that shows no failures either.

This means remotebox (client) cannot login to my server to manage my VMs.

Any ideas what is going on please?

Thanks for the help!